# Line limit in TextEditor (SwiftUI) not working

Tags: swiftui

I've seen a lot of answers that simply say to use the limit limit view modifier but it doesn't seem to work:

```
mport SwiftUI

struct TextEditorTest: View {
    
    @State var text: String = "Type in here"
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
                            
                Text("Sample Text A")
                
                TextEditor(text: $text)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                
                Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct TextEditorTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextEditorTest()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/linelimit(_:)), 
lineLimits(..) is for Text, not TextEditor.

"A view that limits the number of lines that Text instances display."

Comment: It's also listed under `TextEditor` at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor

Comment: Yes correct, I didn't see that one in the TextEditor docs. Still, works for Text but not for TextEditor. Maybe it is saying, you can use lineLimit on TextEditor, but it doesn't work?

Comment: Hmm. You're right, it does mention it in the `TextEditor` docs. But, when reading the docs for `lineLimit(_:)`, Apple says that this method returns "[a] view that limits the number of lines that `Text` instances display". I'm wondering why other text-based views aren't included. Have you tried `frame(height:)` as a workaround instead?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this still seems to be an issue in iOS 17. A workaround is to use `Text` and then overlay the `TextEditor`.

```swift
struct TextView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var fixedHorizontal: Bool = false
    var fixedVertical: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.text)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .hidden()
            .overlay {
                TextEditor(text: self.$text)
                    .padding(.horizontal, -5.0) // default NSTextContainer.lineFragmentPadding
                    .padding(.vertical, -8.0) // default UITextView.textContainerInset
            }
            .clipped() // Stop the TextEditor's extra lines from appearing
            .fixedSize(horizontal: self.fixedHorizontal, vertical: fixedVertical)
    }
}
```